# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden, python3 urlllib, http://cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

С локального компьютера скрипт выполняется нормально. xml файл принимается успешно.
Но когда выполняю следующий скрипт с хостинга pythonanywhere.com появляется ошибка HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чем проблема и как ее обойти?

Часть кода:

```
import urllib, os
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def update_currencies():
    url = 'http://cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp'
    hdr = {}

    hdr['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36'
    hdr['Accept'] =  'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'

    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)

    content = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    tree = ET.parse(content)
    root = tree.getroot()
...
```

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: 403 означает, что запрос до cbr.ru дошёл, сервер понимает запрос, но отказывается его выполнять. Может, сервер не любит ip диапазоны, где pythonanywhere.com хостится (aws). Можно попробовать включить `HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1` и посмотреть, что отправляется в обоих случаях и/или попробовать через прокси (например, свою машину временно прокси сделать).

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему сайт ЦБ РФ очень не любит когда к нему обращаются слишком часто. Добавьте кеш запросов курса интересующей вас валюты (например, сохраняя локально скачанный файл с данными), подождите день и попробуйте ещё раз скачать данные.

Можно также обратиться к какому-то из известных зеркал сервиса ЦБ РФ. У них же можно найти данные по курсам в более удобных для использования формата вроде JSON.

Пример выдачи такого зеркала:

> https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily.xml

Сравните с оригиналом:

> http://cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp

Описание других форматов выдачи [на сайте сервиса](https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/).

Не факт что любые такие сервисы хорошо отнесутся к тому, что вы будете выкачивать курсы валют при каждом заходе посетителя на сайт. Стоит всегда кешировать полученные курсы валют, хотя бы потому что они обновляются [раз в день и только по будним дням](http://www.cbr.ru/ireception/?Prtid=dofr_q_cur).

Answer (score 0):

Использовать прокси-сервер и проверить, сохраняется ли ошибка. Тестить можно Курлом. Если при использовании прокси все работает, то это может означать:

1. Вас забанили за слишком частые обращения. Как говорилось в соседнем ответе - кешируйте результат.
2. Забанен весь хостинг по разным причинам (забанили всю подсеть из-за частых обращений или чего-то такого). Этом случае надо или пользоваться прокси, или менять хостинг. Как вариант, написать слезную просьбу снять бан.